# LESS - target div and anchor within

Tags: less

How can I achieve `.div, .div a{color: #fff;}` in LESS syntax?

```
.div{
    &a{ color: #fff;}
}
```

Above code won't work.

Below code works!

```
.div {
    &, a {color: #fff}
}
```

Comment: Because it will create a selector for `a.div` - I think [this is](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) what you're looking for

Comment: Yes it worked - thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what `extend` is doing there... if it's really just about `.div, .div a {...}` then it's as simple as [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.div%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%2C%20a%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%23fff%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: Good point! Yes it is only about that.